# Grab last file from folder Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is an entire edit since I found what my issue is, but I am still not able to fix this issue.

I am trying to build a function that grabs the last file from a folder based on user input and turn it into a data frame. I have multiple folders assigned as constants. The questions I find are looking for the latest file, which I believe would mess things up as I am modifying multiple files at once, changing their last modified time to all the same time. Even then, I attempted it and it only printed out the variable, `path1` brought back `C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Corona Stats\Country Series` instead of `04-27-2020.csv`

If I enter "Country", it should return the last named file, or first, depending on sorting, named `04-27-2020` from `path1`.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import glob

path1 = r"C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Corona Stats\Country Series"
path2 = r"C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Corona Stats\US Series"
path3 = r"C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Corona Stats\US State Series"
path4 = r"C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Corona Stats\US County Series"

def top_cases():
    top_num = int(input("You're looking for the top...\n"))
    if series == 'Country':

        # this is where I realized I wasn't grabbing the right target

        x = df.sort_values(by='Confirmed', ascending=False)
        x = df['Country'].head(top_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort_values` works with DataFrame, you are using it with Series (this is the reason of the error: `sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'`)

I suggest you modify inside `top_cases` function:

```
    if series == 'Country':
        df = daily_framer(path1)
        x = df.sort_values(by=['Confirmed','Country'], ascending=True).head(top_num)
    elif series == 'US State':
        df = daily_framer(path3)
        x = df.sort_values(by=['Confirmed','State'], ascending=True).head(top_num)
    elif series == 'US County':
        df = daily_framer(path4)
        x = df.sort_values(by=['Confirmed','County'], ascending=True).head(top_num)
```